# QLabel.setText() not working?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I have been trying to get QLabel.setText in PySide working for several days, but no succes.

I have following code(simplified):

```
def GUI(self):
    self.data1=QtGui.QLabel()
    self.data2=QtGui.QLCDNumber()
    self.lcdTimer=QtGui.QLCDNumber()

def tick(time, self):
    self.lcdTimer.display(timetodisplay)  ## this one works
    self.data1.setText(somdatafromlist1)  ## this one not
    self.data2.display(somedatafromlist2) ## this one not
```

So, why I get an errors like this:

```
self.data2.display(somedatafromlist2)
AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QImage' object has no attribute 'display'
self.data1.setText(somedatafromlist1)
TypeError: setText expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

And why is lcdTimer.display() working, but the other ones not. 
What is the second argument .setText neededs?

The problem should not be in the *somedatafromlist1* or *somedatafromlist2*.

I have tried to check out that self.lcdTimer and self.data2 are almost identical.

Comment: The code you have posted works for me.  Are you sure that in your real code `self.data2` is a `QLCDNumber`?  The traceback looks like it's actually a `QImage`.  I suspect that `self.data1` is not actually a `QLabel` as `QLabel.setText` only accepts one argument.

Comment: Look at this: `def tick(time, self):`. It should be `def tick(self, time):`

Comment: Get it working. Problem was that I had also other objects(ImageQt) a few hundreds lines later with names `self.data1` and `self.data2`. `def tick(time, self):` was actually `def tick(self, time):`in my code. How do I mark this solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it working. Problem was that I had also other objects(ImageQt) a few hundreds lines later with names `self.data1` and `self.data2`. `def tick(time, self):` was actually `def tick(self, time):`in my code.